# How to pass a struct by value in x86 assembly

Tags: winapi, assembly, struct, x86, masm

I'm trying to call a function from the windows api in masm.

This is the signature:

```
BOOL WINAPI SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(
  _In_ HANDLE hConsoleOutput,
  _In_ COORD  dwSize
);
```

The COORD structure dwSize is passed by value, but when I try to call it the function fails.

Looks like this:

```
                .DATA
dwSize          COORD   <20, 20>
                .CODE
                INVOKE  SetConsoleScreenBufferSize,
                        hConsoleOutput,
                        dwSize
```

This causes a type error and the program won't assemble. If I pass a reference to the struct, the program assembles but the function does not work. I've tried with other functions that accept structs by value, with no success.

Comment: The INVOKE macro has no idea how to pass a struct by value, it is a C language convention.  How to do it correctly is best done by looking at the disassembly that a C compiler generates.  Ought to produce something like MOV eax, dword ptr [dwSize] and now you can use eax is the 3rd INVOKE argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hans is correct `Invoke` doesn't understand how to pass a struct by value. `COORD` is 2 16-bit values which happens to be the size of a DWORD. In the case of `COORD` you can cast it to a DWORD as a parameter to `Invoke` . This should work:

```
                .DATA
dwSize          COORD   <20, 20>
                .CODE
                INVOKE  SetConsoleScreenBufferSize,
                        hConsoleOutput,
                        DWORD PTR [dwSize]
```

Note: It is important to understand that since `COORD` happened to be the size of a DWORD we could get away with this. For structures that don't have a size that can be pushed on the stack directly you'd have to build the structure on the stack and use the `CALL` instruction rather than `Invoke`.

Answer (score 2):

COORD is just two 16-bit numbers packed together and passed as normal 32-bit number.

MSVC (x86) turns

```
COORD cord = { 0x666, 0x42 };
SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(0, cord);
```

into

```
33db            xor     ebx,ebx

66c745986606    mov     word ptr [ebp-68h],666h    ; store cord.x
66c7459a4200    mov     word ptr [ebp-66h],42h     ; store cord.y

ff7598          push    dword ptr [ebp-68h]        ; push the whole struct
53              push    ebx                        ; push 0
ff1540104000    call    dword ptr [image00400000+0x1040 (00401040)] ; SetConsoleScreenBufferSize
```

After `push`'ing but before the `call` the stack starts with:

```
00000000 00420666 ...
```

---

xor-zeroing a register and then pushing that is a missed optimization vs. `push 0` of an immediate zero.  Storing to the stack first is also only because the source was compiled with optimization disabled.

Comment: That's with optimizations disabled. Turning optimizations on causes the compiler to load a single 32-bit value (`00420666H`) into stack memory.

Comment: @IInspectable It probably depends on whether the value is known at compile time and what you do with the COORD struct after the call.

Comment: It doesn't depend on whether the *value* is known at compile time. What matters is the structure layout, which *is* known at compile time.